# Choose which data to use using promise/async

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried the below to acces both `data` and `json` values, however I can now only acces the `data` values, what can I do to acces the `json` values as well?

```js
const getUser = user => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
 try {
  const read = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.nl/api/public/users?name=' + user);
  const data = JSON.parse(read.text);
  const result = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users/' + data.uniqueId + '/profile');
  const json = JSON.parse(result.text);
  resolve(data, json);
 } catch (error) {
  reject(error);
 }
});
const promise = Promise.resolve(getUser(args[0]));
promise.then(function(data, json) {
 const name = data.name;
 const motto = data.motto;
 const memberSince = data.memberSince;
 const groups = json.groups.length;
 const badges = json.badges.length;
 const friends = json.friends.length;
 const rooms = json.rooms.length;
 message.channel.send(`${name}\n${motto}\n${memberSince}\n${groups || 'N/A'}\n${badges || 'N/A'}\n${friends || 'N/A'}\n${rooms || 'N/A'}\n`);
}).catch(function(err) {
 console.log(err);
 return message.reply(`${args[0]} does not exists.`);
});
```

Comment: `resolve` just takes one argument. If you have multiple pieces of data, put them in an object and resolve with that object.

Comment: Could you show me a example? @NicholasTower - I am not that experienced with JS so I can not image what this would look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you resolve a promise, you pass in a single value with the data you want to resolve it to. If there are multiple pieces of data you want to resolve with, then stick them in an object and resolve with that object

```
const getUser = user => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const read = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.nl/api/public/users?name=' + user);
    const data = JSON.parse(read.text);
    const result = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users/' + data.uniqueId + '/profile');
    const json = JSON.parse(result.text);
    resolve({ data, json }); // <--- created an object with two properties
  } catch (error) {
    reject(error);
  }
});

getUser('someUser')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data)
    console.log(result.json)
  })
```

Additionally, i want to point out that you're creating extra promises where they are not needed. async functions automatically create promises, so your getUser function can just be:

```
const getUser = async (user) => {
  const read = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.nl/api/public/users?name=' + user);
  const data = JSON.parse(read.text);
  const result = await snekfetch.get('https://www.website.com/api/public/users/' + data.uniqueId + '/profile');
  const json = JSON.parse(result.text);
  return { data, json };
}
```